# Iphone6 and Iphone 6Plus Resolution @x2/@x3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, screen-resolution

I've a question about resolution of `Iphone 6` and `Iphone 6 Plus`.
I would like to know something about `@x2` and `@x3`, i really need to be sure !

If i've a fullscreen UIImageView, display on a `Iphone 6(667x375 points)` the size of the containing UIImage have to be `1334x750` because the size in points are `667(@x2)x375(@x2)`, right?

So if i understand, the UIImageView on `Iphone 6Plus` in fullscreen is `736x414` but the resolution is `@x3` then the `UIImage` in the `UIImageView` have to be `2208x1242` because the size in points is `736(@x3)x414(@x3)`, no ?

Then in a general case, i only need to know what is the size of my UIImageView and if the resolution is `@x2` i multiply the size `x2` and if the resolution is `@x3` multiply the size `x3`?

Guys i really need a confirmation and if i'm wrong, please, explain me why !

I'm sorry if you think my question is really stupid but i need to understand how it works.

Cordially :)

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 5):

Lets go for a ride of @1x, @2x and @3x image scaling and content viewer size according to different resolutions in iPhone.

Let understand some basics first

```
Device              Resolution
================================
iPhone 4 & 4S       640×960
iPhone 5, 5C & 5S   640×1136
iPhone 6s           750×1334
iPhone 6P           1242×2208
```

Resolution reference from [this site.](http://www.iphoneresolution.com/)

Now if how to use images with @1x, @2x & @3x.

Lets say you have an imageView in with size of 100W x 100H, to display images properly on all the devices with appropriate resolution without stretching or pixelation your image, one need to create 3 set of images as below according to device.

- iPad 2, iPad mini supports @1x images, required image of size 100x100(WxH)
- iPad, iPad mini supports @2x images, required image of size 200x200(WxH)
- iPhone 4S, 5 & 6 supports @2x images, required image of size 200x200(WxH)
- iPhone 6P supports @3x images, required image of size 300x300(WxH)

Though your `UIImageView` size is 100x100 for all the devices, but image displayed in different devices is different according to their resolutions.

Following size Table will give you more clarification, read more about it in [apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

[image: size chart]

I hope it clears confusion about different resolution images for different devices :)

Comment: Hi bro thanks you so much for help, its clear and simple ! :D
Hope that help other people ! +1